# What is repository in doctrine?

Tags: doctrine

I wonder what a repository means in doctrine?

Could someone please explain?

Comment: @ajsei - thecoshman is being elitist. He thinks the term is self explanatory and forgets that he learned it somewhere himself. Just ignore his comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A repository in a term used by many ORMs (Object Relational Mappers), doctrine is just one of these.

It means the place where our data can be accessed from, a repository of data. This is to distinguish it from a database as a repository does not care how its data is stored.

See the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) from Martin Fowlers "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture".