# Doctrine: What's the difference between Repository and QueryBuilder or DQL?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

For example, for accessing data, I have tried using Repository and Query Builder, I know that's different code but same results, right?

As far as I know, DQL means a different way to write SQL.

But what's the big difference between Repository and the others?
Why should I use one instead of the other?

Comment: "*Why should I use one instead of the other?*" This is impossible to answer without knowing your framework, code structure, your requirements, etc. Maybe you need neither, or something else entirely.  Whatever we say is opinionated though. The question itself is too broad though, as you have multiple questions.

Comment: Info you might make use of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932415/dql-select-in-doctrine-vs-sql-query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674534/what-is-repository-in-doctrine - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176990/proper-repository-pattern-design-in-php